# Rails how to get an array parameter single quoted and comma seperated in a query.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.35

I'm may be wrong but I thought with an array in a paramater, rails was suppose to comman seperate the array when used like below for a query.   I know I can break the param out into a single quoted and comma seperated string.   I was just curious is this can be automatically done by Rails and how I might go about it if so.    Thank You

**Parameters being sent:**

```
Parameters: {"method"=>:get, "id"=>["3", "1", "4"]}
```

**The SQL statement in the controller I'm using:**

```
sql = "SELECT user.user_alias from users " +
"where user.id in (#{params[:id]}) " +
"AND user.user_alias is NOT NULL "
aliases = User.find_by_sql(sql)
```

**The SQL string Rails outputs (the query results in the IN statement are just all togather '314):**

```
SELECT User.user_alias 
from lte_users
where user.id in (314) 
AND user.user_alias is NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEVER**, never, do string concatenation in a SQL query, as someone might use this to perform an **SQL Injection** attack on your webapp.

You should be doing it like this:

```
sql = %Q{SELECT user.user_alias from users
  where user.id in (?) 
  AND user.user_alias is NOT NULL }
aliases = User.find_by_sql([ sql, params[:id] ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you desperately need the performance of not creating ActiveRecord objects for the few records returned, I'd do this idiomatically like:

```
aliases = User.all(
  :conditions => ['id IN (?) AND user_alias IS NOT NULL', params[:id]
  ).map(&:user_alias)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
where user.id in (#{params[:id].join(',')})
```